# changing menu style in dotnet nuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

i am using Alldnnskins-10949 skin in my dotnetnuke. Here i want to change style of the submenu like font etc. But i don't know how it is? Does any one know this?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what level of control you have with your skins.

If you have full control, navigate to your skins folder (Portals subtree) in windows explorer.

Open up your skin's ascx file.

See which nav menu is being used.

It is probably SolParts or one of the Nav Menus that ships with DotNetNuke.

Once you have determined this, you can either watch a training video for styling that specific menu (like at DNN Creative) or try and locate the documentation for it. Usually there is a styling guide in the documentation for each Menu.

For example, the DNNRadMenu Nav Menu Provider has a styling guide here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/menu/menu_apireference.html

Each Nav Menu provider will have something similar, although probably not something as extensive to use as the DNNRadMenu (which, btw, is free to use as of 5.6.2) http://dnnradmenu.codeplex.com/

If you don't have this level of detail, I suggest installing the Web Developer Toolbar in Firefox.

Then, reload firefox and visit your page with that skin.

Press Ctrl-Shift-F and highlight portions of your Nav Menu. This will bring up a yellow menu that shows your current HTML Element, its children, its parents, and each elements' CSS Class.

Now, go to the CSS Menu in the Web Developer toolbar and click EditCSS

This will allow you to tweak the CSS of the page in real-time. It doesn't save the CSS, but it allows you to see what the page would look like IF you did change the CSS Files.

Click the module.css tag and start changing the css styles that you saw using that Ctrl-Shift-F functionality.

Alternatively, you can skip the Ctrl-Shift-F feature and go straight to the Edit CSS Feature. However, browse the CSS File titles for something that feels Nav-Menu-Ish... such as menu.css which shows up if the built-in DNN Menu is being used (5.6.2).

While within the confines of that Edit CSS area, change any styles you can to narrow down which styles affect the menu.

Once you determine the styles that make your menu look the way you want, you can then go and make those changes to the CSS files themselves.

If you have access to the CSS, do it there -- otherwise there are some methods for admins to override the CSS at a site level -- though my experience ends prior to this.

Long story short: Figure out which Nav Provider your skin uses and find the Skinning Documentation for it